# Why does training naive Bayes on a data set in which all the features are repeated increase the conﬁdence of the naive Bayes probability estimates?

Tags: classification, text-mining, naive-bayes

I am looking for a toy example to understand this behavior. Preferebly a text classification one

I read the following from http://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/papers/crf-tutorial.pdf at page 7.

> Furthermore, even when naive Bayes has good classiﬁcation accuracy, its probability estimates tend to be poor. To understand why, imagine training naive Bayes on a data set in which all the features are repeated, that is, x = (x1,x1,x2,x2,...,xK,xK). This will increase the conﬁdence of the naive Bayes probability estimates, even though no new information has been added to the data.

I am able to produce any toy example for which $$p(y) * \sum_{i=1}^k( p(x_i|y))$$ changes by duplicating the features.

Comment: Please write more explicit titles.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of example you are looking for. But to understand this behavior you simply need to consider this: For duplicated variables you have $$p(x_1=k, x_2=k|y)=p(x_1=k|y)=p(x_2=k|y)$$
Yet naive bayes models this as 
$$p_{NaiveBayes}(x_1=k,x_2=k|y)=p(x_1=k|y)p(x_2=k|y)=p(x_1=k,x_2=k|y)^2$$

Comment: "This will increase the conﬁdence of the naive Bayes probability estimates" I am looking for an example which increases probability estimated by naïve Bayes.

Comment: the (normalized) squared probability will be closer to 0 or 1 always. That's exactly what increases the confidence. Say you have a true probability of $p(C | x_1, x_2) = 0.9$ and a uniform prior. The naive bayes probability will be around 0.988.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for proof, here is one.

[PROOF](https://awni.github.io/jiro/practice/2017/09/10/naive-bayes-confidence.html)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please check the tour at https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour. At present, this is a "link-only" answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers are expected to be self-contained, so could you summarize the proof in the answer itself.

Comment: Even though the proof is only a link, this is a much better answer.